# What is wrong with this MySQL query, that has a sub-query with a JOIN, that is supposed to link data from 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a game that users participate in organized by match and contest, with daily matches, and contests held every few years. Scores are based on how closely they predict a sports score for the next day.

There are three tables involved with a query I want to execute. One table contains contest metadata (like name and year), another links matches to contests by MatchId, and another contains the daily standings for each user and MatchId.

I'd like to get a result that gives the average scores by MatchId, along with contest metadata (via the Matches table acting as intermediary). The three tables are:

```
DailyStandings:
-UserId (int)
-MatchId (int)
-MatchScore (double)
-"UserId, MatchId" is the primary key

Matches:
-MatchId (int, primary key)
-ContestId (int)

Contests:
-ContestId(int, primary key)
-Name ( varchar(50) )
-Year (smallint)
```

I am attempting the following query:

```
SELECT DailyStandings.MatchId, AVG(DailyStandings.MatchScore) AS Average, ContestInfo.Name
FROM DailyStandings
INNER JOIN{
 SELECT * FROM Matches
 LEFT JOIN Contests
 ON Matches.ContestId=Contests.ContestId
} ContestInfo
ON DailyStandings.MatchId=ContestInfo.MatchId
WHERE 1
GROUP BY DailyStandings.MatchId ORDER BY DailyStandings.MatchId ASC
```

Note that I am not sure if I should be using an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN here, but neither seems to work.

The sub-query in the INNER JOIN works correctly, and if I get rid of the sub-query (and the ContestInfo.Name in the SELECT) then the main query works.

Perhaps I am making an obvious error, but what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT DailyStandings.MatchId, AVG(DailyStandings.MatchScore) AS Average,
Matches.MatchId, Matches.ContestId 
FROM DailyStandings 
INNER JOIN Matches 
ON DailyStandings.MatchId=Matches.MatchId
Inner Join Contests 
ON Contests.ContestId=Matches.ContestId
WHERE 1 /* Not sure what is "1". Try removing this first and then execute                                        the query. */
GROUP BY DailyStandings.MatchId ORDER BY DailyStandings.MatchId ASC
```

Comment: @Tristan Welcome and glad to be at your help.